# Does anyone have the pycharm external documentation URLs for Scrapy:

Tags: python, scrapy, ide, pycharm, code-documentation

In `settings > tools > python external documentation` you can set the URL and path pattern for pycharm to provide documentation.

Does anyone know the path pattern for scrapy? Nothing is working for me.